# yum install openssl-devel fails

Tags: centos, yum, openssl, repository

Running `yum install openssl-devel` leads to dependency checking errors and do not install it. I guess there is a problem in my repositories however I don't know what is wrong with my installed version of CentOS (`Linux release 7.5.1804`) but I usually need to run yum with `--skip-broken` parmeter. I guess I should set priority for my repositories.

Here is the contents of `CentOS-Base.repo`

```
[root@server1 ~]# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
# CentOS-Base.repo
#
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
# geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
# unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the mirrorlist= does not work for you, as a fall back you can try the
# remarked out baseurl= line instead.
#
#

[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#released updates
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

Here is the erros in output of `yum install openssl-devel` which prompted during 
dependency checking:

```
Error: Package: dracut-network-033-240.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           Requires: dracut = 033-240.el7
           Removing: dracut-033-240.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               dracut = 033-240.el7
           Updated By: dracut-033-535.el7.x86_64 (base)
               dracut = 033-535.el7
           Removing: dracut-033-502.el7.x86_64 (installed)
               dracut = 033-502.el7
           Updated By: dracut-033-535.el7.x86_64 (base)
               dracut = 033-535.el7
Error: Package: libss-1.42.9-7.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           Requires: libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-7.el7
           Removing: libcom_err-1.42.9-7.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-7.el7
           Updated By: libcom_err-1.42.9-12.el7_5.x86_64 (updates)
               libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-12.el7_5
           Removing: libcom_err-1.42.9-10.el7.x86_64 (installed)
               libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-10.el7
           Updated By: libcom_err-1.42.9-12.el7_5.x86_64 (updates)
               libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-12.el7_5
           Available: libcom_err-1.42.9-11.el7.x86_64 (base)
               libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-11.el7
Error: Package: systemd-sysv-208-20.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           Requires: systemd = 208-20.el7
           Removing: systemd-208-20.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               systemd = 208-20.el7
           Updated By: systemd-219-57.el7.x86_64 (base)
               systemd = 219-57.el7
           Removing: systemd-219-42.el7_4.4.x86_64 (installed)
               systemd = 219-42.el7_4.4
           Updated By: systemd-219-57.el7.x86_64 (base)
               systemd = 219-57.el7
Error: Package: systemd-python-208-20.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           Requires: systemd = 208-20.el7
           Removing: systemd-208-20.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               systemd = 208-20.el7
           Updated By: systemd-219-57.el7.x86_64 (base)
               systemd = 219-57.el7
           Removing: systemd-219-42.el7_4.4.x86_64 (installed)
               systemd = 219-42.el7_4.4
           Updated By: systemd-219-57.el7.x86_64 (base)
               systemd = 219-57.el7
Error: Package: e2fsprogs-libs-1.42.9-7.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           Requires: libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-7.el7
           Removing: libcom_err-1.42.9-7.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-7.el7
           Updated By: libcom_err-1.42.9-12.el7_5.x86_64 (updates)
               libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-12.el7_5
           Removing: libcom_err-1.42.9-10.el7.x86_64 (installed)
               libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-10.el7
           Updated By: libcom_err-1.42.9-12.el7_5.x86_64 (updates)
               libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-12.el7_5
           Available: libcom_err-1.42.9-11.el7.x86_64 (base)
               libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-11.el7
Error: Package: libselinux-python-2.2.2-6.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           Requires: libselinux = 2.2.2-6.el7
           Removing: libselinux-2.2.2-6.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libselinux = 2.2.2-6.el7
           Updated By: libselinux-2.5-12.el7.x86_64 (base)
               libselinux = 2.5-12.el7
           Removing: libselinux-2.5-11.el7.i686 (installed)
               libselinux = 2.5-11.el7
           Updated By: libselinux-2.5-12.el7.i686 (base)
               libselinux = 2.5-12.el7
Error: Package: e2fsprogs-1.42.9-7.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           Requires: libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-7.el7
           Removing: libcom_err-1.42.9-7.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-7.el7
           Updated By: libcom_err-1.42.9-12.el7_5.x86_64 (updates)
               libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-12.el7_5
           Removing: libcom_err-1.42.9-10.el7.x86_64 (installed)
               libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-10.el7
           Updated By: libcom_err-1.42.9-12.el7_5.x86_64 (updates)
               libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-12.el7_5
           Available: libcom_err-1.42.9-11.el7.x86_64 (base)
               libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-11.el7
Error: Package: dracut-config-rescue-033-240.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           Requires: dracut = 033-240.el7
           Removing: dracut-033-240.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               dracut = 033-240.el7
           Updated By: dracut-033-535.el7.x86_64 (base)
               dracut = 033-535.el7
           Removing: dracut-033-502.el7.x86_64 (installed)
               dracut = 033-502.el7
           Updated By: dracut-033-535.el7.x86_64 (base)
               dracut = 033-535.el7
Error: Package: libselinux-utils-2.2.2-6.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           Requires: libselinux = 2.2.2-6.el7
           Removing: libselinux-2.2.2-6.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libselinux = 2.2.2-6.el7
           Updated By: libselinux-2.5-12.el7.x86_64 (base)
               libselinux = 2.5-12.el7
           Removing: libselinux-2.5-11.el7.i686 (installed)
               libselinux = 2.5-11.el7
           Updated By: libselinux-2.5-12.el7.i686 (base)
               libselinux = 2.5-12.el7
Error: Package: libgudev1-208-20.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           Requires: systemd = 208-20.el7
           Removing: systemd-208-20.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               systemd = 208-20.el7
           Updated By: systemd-219-57.el7.x86_64 (base)
               systemd = 219-57.el7
           Removing: systemd-219-42.el7_4.4.x86_64 (installed)
               systemd = 219-42.el7_4.4
           Updated By: systemd-219-57.el7.x86_64 (base)
               systemd = 219-57.el7
Error: Package: krb5-workstation-1.12.2-14.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           Requires: krb5-libs(x86-64) = 1.12.2-14.el7
           Removing: krb5-libs-1.12.2-14.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               krb5-libs(x86-64) = 1.12.2-14.el7
           Updated By: krb5-libs-1.15.1-19.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               krb5-libs(x86-64) = 1.15.1-19.el7
           Removing: krb5-libs-1.15.1-8.el7.x86_64 (installed)
               krb5-libs(x86-64) = 1.15.1-8.el7
           Updated By: krb5-libs-1.15.1-19.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               krb5-libs(x86-64) = 1.15.1-19.el7
           Available: krb5-libs-1.15.1-18.el7.x86_64 (base)
               krb5-libs(x86-64) = 1.15.1-18.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem

** Found 936 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
ModemManager-1.6.0-2.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with ModemManager-1.1.0-6.git20130913.el7.x86_64
ModemManager-glib-1.6.0-2.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with ModemManager-glib-1.1.0-6.git20130913.el7.x86_64
1:NetworkManager-1.8.0-11.el7_4.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:NetworkManager-1.0.0-14.git20150121.b4ea599c.el7.x86_64
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if either your RPM DB or YUM are out of sync and/or date with each other or their upstreams.

I'd do the following:

```
$ sudo yum clean all
$ sudo yum update -y
```

If things still seem hung up check to make sure you don't have RPMs installed that are from a YUM repo that was out of sync. You'll typically see packages installed multiple times:

```
$ sudo rpm -qa | grep -i 'dracut'
```

You'll see 2 items with the same name if this is the case. To resolve it you typically remove it, but this might choose challenging. You could try doing this:

```
$ sudo yum reinstall <pkg>
```

Comment: Possibly helpful— was for a similar situation: [yum history sync](https://serverfault.com/a/883576/293440)